# GetAddressByName and Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, winsock

I've taken over maintenance of a Windows Service that was written many years ago.
My first task is to get the service running on Windows 7.
WinDbg shows that the service is erroring out on a call to GetAddressByName. (GetAddressByName returns 0 and the service shuts down.)

According to MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), GetAddressByName is not available for use with Winsock v. 2.

**Does the above mean that GetAddressByName will not work with Windows 7?** (Does Winsock 1.x work on Windows 7?)
(Any recommendations for a function to use instead of GetAddressByName? )

I'm looking to see if anyone else has done this before.

Alternatively (GetAddressByName is supported on Win 7), any suggestions for debugging a call to GetAddressByName that's returning 0?

Best regards,
Mitch

Comment: First sentence in the documentation for [GetAddressByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738517.aspx): *"**GetAddressByName** is no longer available for use as of Windows Sockets 2. Instead, use the functions detailed in [Protocol-Independent Name Resolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740101.aspx)."*

Answer (score 1):

`GetAddressByName()` is a legacy function from WinSock 1.x.  It was removed in WinSock 2.0.  Apps using WinSock 2.x should use [`getaddrinfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx), if not [`gethostbyname()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524.aspx) (which is still available).

In any case, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738517.aspx) for `GetAddressByName()` says:

> If the function succeeds, **the return value is the number of CSADDR_INFO data structures written to the buffer pointed to by lpCsaddrBuffer**.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is SOCKET_ERROR( –1). To get extended error information, call GetLastError

Since `GetAddressByName()` is returning 0, it is succeeding but no addresses are being returned.  Make sure the service code is handling that fact and not trying to access invalid buffer data.